# Bluetoothctl on Raspberry Pi 1 - Troubleshooting

Tags: raspbian-jessie, bluetooth

I have been trying to make the Raspberry Pi work regarding Bluetooth using the command `bluetoothctl`. I've been using `Wheezy`before and now I started using `Jessie`, because I couldn't find an image for `Wheezy`anymore for my `Raspberry Pi 1` after it got infected by malware.

What I want to say by this is that regarding hardware, it worked, so it is a software issue.

I've been trying to pair my Bluetooth `A2DP` transmitter `B-speech TX2` for quite some time with my pi-1 and my plugged in `Belkin Bluetooth 4.0 USB Adapter` BT-USB-dongle and everything it says is this:`Attempting to pair with 00:0A:1D:16:60:50
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed` I even got that far to reach the `authentication failed` but I don't remember how I managed to do this. The thing is that this is very time consuming and I would like to know, where I can get some `logs`, more information about why it doesn't work and maybe some `troubleshooting` regarding `bluetoothctl`.

This is the bluetooth part of the `dmesg` output:

```
[   11.362733] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   11.362870] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.362900] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.362919] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.362971] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.680116] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[   11.697233] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[   11.699286] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[   11.704076] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd failed with error -2
[   11.704105] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd not found
[   17.110718] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   17.110733] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   17.110841] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Running `sudo journalctl -f` ("follow" mode) in a window will show you all log messages generated on the system.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Thanks. What do you do with `bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd failed with error -2` and `Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd not found`?

Comment: No idea. You should add to your question information about the device you're trying to connect; without knowing even what that is pretty much everything's going to be a mystery to us.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bluetooth adapter you're using has a chip in it that needs to have firmware loaded into it to work properly.

As per [this plugable.com blog entry](https://plugable.com/2014/06/23/plugable-usb-bluetooth-adapter-solving-hfphsp-profile-issues-on-linux/), you need to download a copy of the firmware from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/plugable/bin/fw-0a5c_21e8.hcd) (the firmware is [the same for the A0 and A1 revisions](http://support.plugable.com/plugable/topics/need-bcm20702a1-0a5c-21e8) of the chip)

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/plugable/bin/fw-0a5c_21e8.hcd
```

and then copy it into `/lib/firmware` under the path and filename given in the error message:

```
sudo cp fw-0a5c_21e8.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd
```